# X-axis values appear twice when using scale_y_break and scale_x_continuous at the same time

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggbreak

I made a barplot with a break in the y-axis. I would like to define the x-axis values (I want all of them to appear in the plot), it's working with the scale_x_continuous function, but the values appear twice. Here's my code and the plot. Any suggestions?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)

df <- data.frame(n=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 ratio=c(1.3,1.5,10,1.2,1.6))

head(df)

ggplot(df, aes(x=n, y=ratio)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.75, fill="#2D3250") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = as.character(df$n), breaks = df$n) +
  scale_y_break(c(2, 3), scales = 0.2, space = 0.3, expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to why it's doing it, I'm not sure - seems like a bug.

As to fixing it, you can give `scale_x_continuous` a duplicated axis with no breaks:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)

df <- data.frame(n=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 ratio=c(1.3,1.5,10,1.2,1.6))

head(df)
#>   n ratio
#> 1 1   1.3
#> 2 2   1.5
#> 3 3  10.0
#> 4 4   1.2
#> 5 5   1.6

ggplot(df, aes(x=n, y=ratio)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.75, fill="#2D3250") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = as.character(df$n), breaks = df$n,  sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = NULL)) +
  scale_y_break(c(2, 3), scales = 0.2, space = 0.3, expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked! It obviously shouldn't put the second axis in there, but the package help page seems to [gloss over the issue](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html#feature-11-compatible-with-dual-axis) slightly. You could raise an issue at GitHub, though I part suspect it's complex a problem to solve in the code!

Answer (score 1):

to me it looks like you don't need the scale_x_continuous level:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=n, y=ratio)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.75, fill="#2D3250") +
      #scale_x_continuous(labels = as.character(df$n), breaks = df$n) +
      scale_y_break(c(2, 3), scales = 0.2, space = 0.3, expand = c(0,0))
```

aes(x=n,... defines the x-axis values already

Comment: This is not the data I am working with, it's just an example to show you the problem. In the original dataset, I have more x values and in that case, not all of them appear in the plot. This is why I need to use the scale_x_continuous function. Probably it wasn't the best example I used, sorry for that.